# Set Background Color of Navigation Drawer in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to set a background color of Navigation bar. I tried all the methods but none of method is working. I also found simmilar posts and applied those changes also.

My XML file

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
       android:id="@+id/viewnav"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:background="#FFFFFF"
       android:theme="@style/navigationTheme"
       app:headerLayout="@layout/menu_header"
       app:elevation="2dp"
       app:itemTextColor="@color/md_blue_100"
       app:menu="@menu/main_menu" />
```

I also tried in setting style.xml

```
<style name="navigationTheme" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.NavigationView" >

        <item name="colorPrimary">
            @color/md_purple_500
        </item>

        <item name="colorControlHighlight">
            @color/md_white_1000
        </item>

        <item name="android:background">
            @color/md_white_1000
        </item>

    </style>
```

Any idea how can i change the color?

It's looking like below even after applying suggested changes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExPOy.jpg)

My Activity.xml is:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context=".Home"
    android:id="@+id/drwnav">


   <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
       android:id="@+id/viewnav"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:background="@drawable/navigation_background"
       android:theme="@style/navigationTheme"
       app:elevation="2dp"
       app:headerLayout="@layout/menu_header"
       app:itemTextColor="@color/md_blue_100"
       app:menu="@menu/main_menu" />


   <LinearLayout..... some other content

 </LinearLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/menu_header"
```

Change `@layout/menu_header` background color to `@android:color/transparent`. or change color what you want to `@layout/menu_header`

Comment: It's already set and that's limited to only header part. I want entire navigation view color change

Answer (score 0):

Create a new empty drawable file and named it as "navigation_background" and then
paste this code in it:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dp"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:endColor="#FFFF"
    android:startColor="#FFFF"
    android:type="linear" />
<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
```

and then in your activity_main.xml :

```
   <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
   android:id="@+id/viewnav"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="start"
   android:background="@drawable/navigation_background"
   android:theme="@style/navigationTheme"
   app:headerLayout="@layout/menu_header"
   app:elevation="2dp"
   app:itemTextColor="@color/md_blue_100"
   app:menu="@menu/main_menu" />
```

Comment: In gradient, place your own selected start and end color. If you don't want corner, then remove it.

Comment: That also did not solve my issue. Navigation view still has black background and icon also not properly visible.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. It's my mobile dark mode Settings which was getting applied.